# What is the fastest and most efficient way to Hbase bulk delete

Tags: hadoop, hbase

What is the fastest and most efficient way to bulk delete hbase records? Hbase client API or a  MapReduce job?

Comment: Hbase cleint is faster

Comment: what's the reason for that?

Answer (score 1):

The HBase Client API does not allow to do bulk deletions unless you know the row keys of the cells you want to delete.

The BulkDeleteEndpoint can be leveraged to do bulk deletes based on the results of a scanner.

Comment: Can you direct me to a tutorial or a web site that would help me to learn about "BulkDeleteEndpoint".. Because i'm really really new to hadoop and hbase..Thanks

Comment: You can check the [HBase doc](https://hbase.apache.org/devapidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/coprocessor/example/BulkDeleteEndpoint.html)

Answer (score 1):

The fastest and most efficient way for large contiguous datasets is to drop entire regions by deleting their HDFS directories and removing them from the META table. This incurs virtually no IO so it's arguably almost free. 
Note, however that this is not yet available directly through the high level APIs, so you have to script / code it in order to get it done.

Here's an example, from the HBase mailing lists, of how you could do it using the shell.

> 1. Close the region from the shell (read up on how this works using shell
>      help -- don't do unassign)
> 2. Then just delete the content of the region in HDFS once the region is
>      closed (the region dir name in HDFS is the same as the region encoded name,
>      the last portion of a region name -- check refguide).
> 3. After the delete in HDFS, call assign region.

Source http://search-hadoop.com/m/YGbbl9ZaSQ2HLT&subj=Re+Delete+a+region+from+hbase

Comment: Thanks .. I'll try to do that.

Answer (score 0):

HBase Client API is faster because you perform operations directly on the database while using MapReduce which means that tasks will run over jobs and that's take time according to my experience. 
Over than that HBase will allow you to run specific operations in Column families that MapReduce can't do.